# unity C#: how to set an integer to a negative number inside an if statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have declared a variable named RandomX and RandomY. I use a random generator function to return a random number between -1 to 1. I then use an if statement to check the number that is generated. If the number generated (RandomX or RandomY) is less than -0.4 then I want to set the variable movementX to -1. If the number is greater than 0.4 I was to set the variable movementX to 1. If neither of these are true I want to set the value to 0.

Here is what I have, but for some reason if the number is less than -0.4 instead of it setting the number to -1 it sets the number to 0. What am I missing?

```
float randomX = Random.Range (-1f,1f);

if (randomX < -0.4)
{
    movementX = (-1);
}
if (randomX > 0.4)
{
    movementX = movementX * -1;
}
else 
{
    movementX = 0;
}

randomY = Random.Range (-1f,1f);

Debug.Log (randomY);
if (randomY < -0.4)
{
    movementY = -1;
}
if (randomY > 0.4)
{
    movementY = 1;
}
else 
{
    movementY = 0;
}
```

Comment: What should happen when your input is between -0.4 and 0.4? Shell it stay the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here.

```
if (randomX < -0.4)
{
    movementX = -1;
}
```

Here you assign `-1` if the condition fits. However afterwards you do this:

```
if (randomX > 0.4)
{
    movementX = movementX * -1;
}
else 
{
    movementX = 0;
}
```

Which will check if the new value is less `0.4` which it apparently is now. Furthermore when your input is greater than 0.4 it should return 1 if I understand you correctly.

Write this instead:

```
if (randomX < -0.4)
{
    movementX = -1;
}
else if (randomX > 0.4)
{
    movementX = 1;
}
else 
{
    movementX = 0;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. I did have to change one part of the code. The else if (randomX > 0.4) { movementX = movementX * -1; } needed to be changed to just movementX = -1. The way you had it set was setting movementX to -1 if randomX was greater than 0.4 and if it was less than 0.4. Thank you for putting me on the right track!

Comment: I already assumed this, but you did not mention this at all in your question, so I could not ensure this and stayed at what you wrote in your code.

Comment: See my update, you also forgot to set your result to 1 if your input is greater 0.4, I changed it accordingly.